# Build database from xsd and wsdl in SQL Server 2012

Tags: t-sql, xsd, sql-server-2012, wsdl

Sorry for the naive question but although I googled a lot and found some simple examples, I've not been able to transpose these to my problem, that has around 100 tables and is, for me, quite complicated.

I need to build a Database to contain information retrieved from eBay through their API.

For the time being I've been using only a couple of tables and it has been easier for me to build manually, but now I need to build the full structure of the database and I was looking for a way not only to avoid a lot of manual (and unnecessary work) but to have the database according to specification.

XSD and WSDL are available at the following address:

- http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/latest/ebaySvc.xsd
- http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/latest/eBaySvc.wsdl

Is there a way to generate all tables with all columns correctly set in size and format directly from xsd and/or wsdl files attached?

Thanks

Joe

Comment: From what I know, there is no open source project which would do what you need. Out of the box functionality will not work if only because the schema uses proprietary annotations to provide additional constraints (e.g. size of the field). If you're interested in a proprietary solution, contact me using the support address on my website.

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for answering..
well, actually I thought that xsd and or wsdl did include all constraints, pk, fieldType and Size: 
I read some rows and found that for some fields these info was included, and I (wrongly) thought that was for all Tables and Fields..  
Therefore my question is.. what are used xsd and wsdl for?
but surely I will find the answer googling for a while.
Therefore to do what I have in mind it is required the DLL?
Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure about the DLL you're referring to... is it the compiled code generated by MS tools from wsdl/xsd? If yes, then you cannot really use that to achieve what you need, nor is there a known path from the DLL to what you want. You would need hundreds of tables to store the model as described by the XSD. There are mechanisms to "naturally" collapse some of the entities, what some may call "denormalization" of the types in the XSD... We do support all of this, but I am somewhat convinced it would not be what you've been thinking or expecting.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your time.
Actually there is no DLL supplied: I was asking (indirectly) what it is required to create a database? from what I understood it require a DLL or SQL Command File: With XSD and WSDL it is not possible to do anything.. And beside this I've not understood the meaning and scope of XSD and WSDL.. :-(

Comment: In addition to XML validation, documentation, etc. XSDs can be used to create databases. For relational databases such as SQL Server 2012, you can write your own logic, or you can use a tool that will supply the logic to map an XSD to a logical model, and then forward engineer it into a specific physical model. I've actually tried your XSD and it works fine. Without tuning, the transformation yields 1312 tables. What I mean by tuning... is that many tables are created (e.g. FreeGalleryPlusEnabledDefinitionType is an empty type, used as a base type by FeatureDefinitionsType)...

Comment: (cont'd) If one gets rid of these "empty" types, maybe 100 or so go away; or if some are collapsed (de-normalized)... you can get the number down to a couple of hundreds... but then you would have to analyse , to make sure that in the process you're not losing some relationships that may be relevant to what you're trying to do... You really have to make sure you need a relational database... other than that yes, it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [xsd2db on sourceforge](http://xsd2db.sourceforge.net/)

Use with extraordinary caution, as it drops and recreates databases without warning!

Example command-line parameters:

```
-f -l  servername -n databasename -s c:\workspace\xsd2db\Schemas\schema.xsd -t Sql
```

As is, it references an old version of ADODB in the DataSchemaAdapter project. Just delete that and add the NuGet package of the same name.

All these years later, and it still seems to work well in VS2019